# Python function annotation with tuple and N pd DataFrames?

Tags: python, annotations, typing

I have a function that returns `N=4` pandas DataFrames. I can clearly specify all types for the function like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Tuple 

def preprocess(df: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]:
    pass
```

but it's a bit verbose and I would prefer a more pythonic annotation in case I have to return a tuple with generally `N` elements. Since the return types are specified as a tuple and for tuple initialization there is a convenient Python feature to replace long initializations like `(1,1,1,1,1,1)` by simply writing `(1,)*6`, I thought a similar approach would possibly work here as well:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Tuple

N = 4 

def preprocess(df: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame] * N:
    pass
```

But this throws an error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: '_GenericAlias' and 'int'
```

How can I annotate my function accordingly?

**Edit:** My goal is not to dynamically set the annotations. I'm only curious if there exists a pythonic way to declare any-length tuples as a return value, instead of having to write long annotations like `Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]`. Imagine if a function was to return `N=20` objects in a tuple, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the length of the annotation is variable, you can use the ellipsis built-in, `...`, to indicate additional items.

```
def preprocess(df: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, ...]:
    pass
```

If you want to dynamically set your annotation, you can do so by defining your function with an annotation of length 1, and then modifying it (the return portion of the function annotation) to have the desired number of arguments.

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Tuple

N = 4

def preprocess(df: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame]:
    pass

preprocess.__annotations__['return'] *= N

help(preprocess)
# prints:
Help on function preprocess in module __main__:

preprocess(df: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame) -> Tuple[pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, 
      pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, 
      pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, 
      pandas.core.frame.DataFrame]
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about `...`, thanks for the info! Yet, I'm curious of what the preferred way to specify a fixed-length `Tuple` would be.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically create annotations, or change annotation on-the-fly during run-time?  You really should not do the 2nd.

Comment: I only want to define the output type which is a fixed length of tuple with pandas dataframes. I don't want to dynamically set this, I was just wondering if there is a generalized way to declare length-N tuples to avoid having to write long annotations like `Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]`

Comment: There is no generalized way that I know of using the standard syntax.  See my update on modifying the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is possible with `tuple`, but you can return `list[pd.DataFrame]`. It may even make more sense than a generic-sized tuple, in some scenarions.

Your question is definitely interesting, maybe it should be a PEP if there isn't a similar one yet!